# How do I turn off notices only?

Tags: 8

I want to show only warnings and errors but I want to turn-off notices. How can I turn off notices?

In my settings.php, I have this code:

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
```

What value should I put there?

Answer (score 3):

This configuration aligns with the options at Manage > Configuration > Development > Logging and Errors (/admin/config/development/logging).

There are 4 error level options available. The levels with their corresponding values, i.e. the actual value for `$config['system.logging']['error_level']` are:

1. None: `hide`
2. Errors and warnings: `some`
3. All messages: `all`
4. All messages, with backtrace information: `verbose`

For example, to only display errors and warnings, replace your current line with:

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'some';
```